# Python API request getting error TypeError: Session.request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'version'

Tags: python, api

I have an API where I am pulling the results, but after updating my SDK to Python v10, I an not able to run pull from API and I am getting

> TypeError: Session.request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'version'

```
import os
import json
import requests
from http import HTTPStatus

client_id = ""
client_secret = ""

os.environ["DX_GATEWAY"] = "http://api.com"
os.environ["DX_CLIENT_ID"] = client_id
os.environ["DX_CLIENT_SECRET"] = client_secret

dx_request = requests.Request()

path = "/path/to/api"

params = {
    "Type": "abc",
    "Id": "def",
    "limit": 999,
    "Category": "abc"
}

params_str = "&".join([f"{k}={v}" for k, v in params.items()])
url = "?".join([path, params_str])

vulns = requests.get( ## here is where the error is coming from.
    url=url,
    version=1,
)

if vulns.status_code != int(HTTPStatus.OK):
    raise RuntimeError("API call did not return expected response: " + str(vulns))

response_data = vulns.json()    
print(json.dumps(response_data))
```

Error is coming from
Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please edit the question and add the whole error traceback message.

Comment: @JohnGordon i updated the script and the error is coming from `vulns = requests.get(
    url=url,
    version=1,
)`

Comment: `requests.get` does not take a `version` argument (which is exactly what the error message is telling you). You can find all the acceptable arguments [in the documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/).

Comment: Okay, so. The error points at the code that says `requests.get(url=url, version=1)`, and directly says that the `version=` part is not allowed. What exactly is confusing? Did you try to read the documentation for `requests.get`, in order to understand what is supported? What effect are you expecting the `version=1` part to have, and why? "after updating my SDK to Python v10" - "SDK" isn't terminology Python uses (are you using a particular IDE, perhaps?), and there is no version 10 of Python (did you mean 3.10?).

Comment: Also, just to make sure: you understand that `requests` is *not part of the Python standard library*, but is installed third-party - right?